# GAE bulk upload programmatically

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a python script that is intended to run on my local machine every night. It's goal is to pull data from a third party server, do some processing on it, and execute bulk upload to GAE datastore.

My issue though is hot to run bulk upload from a python script. All examples I have seen (including Google's documentation) use command line "appcfg.py upload_data ..." and as far as I can see appcfg.py and bulkloader.py do not expose any API that is guaranteed not to change.

My two options as I see them now is to either execute "appcfg.py upload_data ..." command from my python script, which seems a roundabout way of doing things. Or to directly call appcfg.py's internal methods, which means I have to recode tings in case they change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appengine can run cron jobs. All you need is to write is a single script which pulls the data from third party server and upload it to appengine engine, Appenigne will do the rest for you. [Appengine cron](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html) this has everything you need to know about running a cron job in appengine

Comment: The reason I decided to use bulkloader is that the data that I get is in multiple csv files. With some minimal set up, bulkloader does all the work of uploading them for me. As much as I understand, if I use a cron job, I would have to parse the files and create and save entity objects myself. I would probably bite the bullet and use cron if there are no way around it.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. But we come full circle. Does bulkloader provide an API that would not change in the future; is doing something like "bulkloader.main(argv_that_I_create)" safe?

Comment: You cannot trust any API to *not* change in the future. However good APIs only change if truly necessary and they don't suddenly change without any notice/documentation.

Comment: Parsing CSV files is not difficult - the Python `csv` module does it for you. Writing your own code is probably the best approach here - bulkloader is designed for 'one off' and backup bulkloading/downloading. Running it from within App Engine certainly won't work.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is now outdated. Please see the below link for my latest answer for bulk upload data to app engine.

[How to upload data in bulk to the appengine datastore? Older methods do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27891104/1179958)